# How can I make my Azure pipeline fail when code coverage requirement is not met?

Tags: spring, kotlin, gradle, azure-pipelines, jacoco

The project I am working on (Spring, Kotlin, Gradle, jaCoCo) requires that the code base always has a code coverage of at least 70%.

I am trying to integrate this requirement into the pipeline that is ran on every push to the repository. The way I have it set up right now is for the build to fail when the coverage requirement is not met.

I've achieved this by utilising the jacocoTestCoverageVerification task. The problem is that in the pipeline the build step fails when this happens and the test results aren't published properly, because the pipeline skips over it when this happens.

In the logs of the build steps the coverage is logged properly (i.e. jacoco logs where coverage requirements aren't met and by what margin) but on DevOps they are nowhere to be found as they are not uploaded as test results.

I would like for the pipeline to publish the results even if the build step fails. How would I go about this?